# Store Multiline String from Cassandra to DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I have a Cassandra as

> CREATE TABLE ks.table1 (f1 text, f2 text)

table with value of f1 as

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

This is a \n separated, multi-line string in Cassandra
WHen I read this field into a dataframe (Spark/ Scala) I get just

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Question :
Does Spark Dataframe or RDD have a limitation on length of String that is read from Cassandra ?

Comment: Are you sure the output isn't just getting truncated?

results.show(20, False)

Comment: No.. there is no truncate or trimming of data.. Strangely, I was writing data to a file and opening it in vi editor.. but when I opened the file in Notepad++, I was able to see the actual data as-is from Cassandra.. Weird !